# Python script to find nth prime number

Tags: python, if-statement, range, primes, factoring

I'm new to Python and I thought I'd try to learn the ropes a bit by writing a function to find the nth prime number, however I can't get my code to work properly. No doubt this is due to me missing something fundamental, but I'd appreciate your help in finding where it went wrong!

```
c=2
n=input("Which prime would you like? ")
n=int(n)
a=[]
l=len(a)

while l<=n:
    if c==2:
        a.append(c)
    elif (c % 2 ==0): #c is even
        break
    elif (c % 2 !=0): #c is odd
        if c<7:
            a.append(c)
        elif c >=7:
            for i in range(3,int((c+1)/2)):
                if (c % i ==0):
                    break
            else:
                a.append(c)
    else:            
        c+=1
a[n]
```

Thanks!
Andrew

Comment: For starters, both `l` and `n` never change inside the loop, so how will the loop condition ever be `False`.

Comment: You have to call `l=len(a)` in the loop and then check whether `l <= n`. Or just remove `l=len(a)` and replace `while l<=n` with `while len(a)<=n`.

Comment: Every integer is either odd or even, therefore the final `else: c+=1` will never be executed.

Comment: Thanks guys, all very helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a start. This checks whether the number N is divisible by all numbers from `2` to `int(sqrt(N)) + 1`, where the `int` function truncates the square root of N. The `all()` function in python returns `True` if all members of a list satisfy some condition (here not zero). You should set an upper bound as this is not very efficient for really large `n`. I'll leave that to you.

```
def nthprime(n):
    import math
    start = 2
    count = 0
    while True:
        if all([start % i for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(start)) + 1)]) != 0:
            count += 1
            if count == n:
                return start
        start += 1 



In [91]: nthprime(50)
Out[91]: 229

In [92]: nthprime(100)
Out[92]: 541
```

Tested with [this](https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/index.php#nth).

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer solved your problem you can mark it accepted (that will register).

Answer (score -1):

Try like this?

```
print 2

for i in range(3,1000):

    b = False
    for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0:
                b=True

    if b == False:
        print i
```