# Question about Project Euler problem 7 in Python

Tags: python

I've been figuring about question 7 of project Euler. I've worked out the 
my Python code, but it has no output, and I don't know if there are any grammatical and logical problems. Would you please help me check what's wrong with it? Here is the original question:

By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13. What is the 10 001st prime number?

```
def isprime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
x = 3
counter = 2
while counter <= 10001:
    if isprime(x):
        counter += 1
        x += 2
    else:
        x += 2
print (x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script to find nth prime number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039350/python-script-to-find-nth-prime-number)

Comment: Your implementation will eventually print something, though it will work _much_ faster if you notice that it is enough to check the divisors until `sqrt(n)` instead of `n` in `isprime()`.

Comment: It has output, but it takes a very long time for it to appear. You need a more efficient way to determine primality. (Very few of those problems can be solved by brute force alone.)

Comment: @bereal yeah, I got the output after about 10 minutes.

Comment: @never0lie with the mentioned fix it's a split second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic works fine after the following fixes:

1. Correct indentation.
2. Subtract 2 from your end result.

Note your implementation is inefficient. However, it does work.

```
def isprime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

x = 3

counter = 2

while counter <= 10001:
    if isprime(x):
        counter += 1
        x += 2
    else:
        x += 2

print(x-2)  # 104743
```

Comment: Why 2 needs to be subtracted? And how can I make it more efficient?

Comment: Because when a prime is found, both counter is incremented by 1 and `x` is incremented by 2. Here, you'll find the prime number is incremented by 2 to 104745 (which is obviously non-prime). Of course, you can make the code cleaner / more efficient, but there are *many* such questions on SO and this isn't what OP is asking.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have got it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to check the divisibility up to the number, just check till to the square root of the number.

```
import math

def is_prime(num):
    if (num < 2):
        return False
    elif (num == 2):
        return True
    else:
        divisible = False
        for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num)+1)):
            if (num%i == 0):
                divisible = True
        return not(divisible)
    
count = 2
number = 3

while count != 10001:
    number += 2
    if is_prime(number):
        count += 1

print(number)
```